# com.sun HttpContext handler called multiple times

Tags: java, http, httpserver

I am trying to make a simple HttpServer which serves dynamically created webpages. However, I noticed that my handler for the HttpServer's HttpContext is called multiple times, regardless of what browser I use. The relevant code is attached below:

Main method in main class:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        try {
            HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(80), 0);
            HttpContext context = server.createContext("/");
            context.setHandler(exchange -> {
                switch (exchange.getRequestMethod()) {
                    case "GET": httpGet(exchange); break;
                    case "HEAD": httpHead(exchange); break;
                    // ... redacted for brevity
                }
            });
            server.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Handler in main class:

```
    private static final void httpGet(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(exchange);
        String[] resource = exchange.getRequestURI().toString().substring(1).split("/");
        String page;
        if (resource.length <= 0) {
            // serve the home page
            page = "home";
        } else if (resource[0].equals("stock")) {
            if (resource.length < 2) {
                // display stock index
                page = "index";
            } else {
                String ticker = resource[1];
                if (resource.length < 3) {
                    // display stock summary
                    page = "summary";
                } else {
                    String targetPage = resource[2];
                    page = DatabaseAbstraction.getPage(ticker, targetPage);
                }
            }
        } else {
            page = DatabaseAbstraction.get404Page();    
        }
        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, page.getBytes().length);
        exchange.getResponseBody().write(page.getBytes());
        exchange.getResponseBody().close();
        return;
    }
```

The DatabaseAbstraction delegates page generation and will (in the future) handle page caching. My primary concern is the *handler itself*, not the database methods, seems to be called anywhere from three to five times regardless of which browser is used to load it.

I figure it might be the timeout, but does anyone have a definite answer or experience with what would cause this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: how many times is it called? and how many times do you send a request?

Comment: Hi, the number of times it is called is seemingly random. Sometimes it is only called once, other times I have seen it called up to four times. I'm not sure how many requests are sent; I am trying to access it from my browser. Do you think I should Wireshark it?

Comment: HttpContext executes per request that's why i'm asking how many request you are firing from your browser